# How to automatically reboot my pc every 3 hours?

Tags: 14.04, reboot

My pc runs a program when it boots. Sometimes the program stops working after a few hours, but it will work fine when it reboots. So, I want to schedule my pc to reboot every 3 hours to prevent the program to be stopped. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

edit: The program doesn't stop, it just doesn't work with the maximum power of the pc but I need it to work with full power.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to prevent it from stopping OR make it restart automatically when it does? Can be done easily with a cron job

Comment: Definitely it would be better, but I don't know any option to do these. The program is Sgminer which I'm talking about. I know a software CGWatcher in Windows to do what you told, but I don't know any in Ubuntu.

Comment: take a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: That's right Jacob Vlijm and JohonnyEnglish. Cron job is axactly what I wanted.

Comment: Jacob, sgminer is for "mining" which is related to cryptocurrency. And yes, it is listed.

Comment: There isn't any sgminer.desktop there. Actually, it has not been installed, I just use it without installing.

Comment: ok, then what is the command to run it?

Comment: There's an autostart file for it in Home: sh m.sh.  But it's folder in Home is sgminer then sh sgminer.sh

Comment: restarting system is not needed. You just need to relaunch the sgminer service ;)

Comment: Sgminer won't relaunch correctly when a GPU is dead or sick, until I restart the pc.

Comment: Jacob, it doesn't matter how I start sgminer, since it starts automatically when the pc boots. I want run reboot command every 3 hours. Is this right for cron job: * */3 * * * sudo reboot  ? I guess my command is not right.

Comment: _Answer:_ Install Windows and make sure "automatic updates" are enabled.

Comment: @IQAndreas: That was hilarious! :D

Comment: The answer is here take a look at this link 

<http://askubuntu.com/questions/13730/how-can-i-schedule-a-nightly-reboot>

Comment: nope at least dude I also need rep as much as you do

Comment: but actually due to my flag you should answer it but at least vote my comment

Comment: As Creator said in the comments the answer is here:
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/13730/how-can-i-schedule-a-nightly-reboot%3E>

Comment: It's weird. I chose "Answer your question" and wrote "As Creator said...". It was auto-converted to comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work, but I am not sure about the command, since I am not familiar with gminer.

**The script**

Paste the text below in an empty file, save it as check_gminer.py, save it somewhere:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import getpass

curruser = getpass.getuser()
service = "gminer"

def createlist_runningprocs():
    processesb = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "-u", curruser], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process_listb = (processesb.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")).split("\n")
    return process_listb

def runsornot():
    runningprocs_list = createlist_runningprocs()
    if not application[:15] in str(runningprocs_list):
        subprocess.Popen(["sh", "m.sh"])
    else:
        pass

runsornot()
```

**Editing cronfile**

Add the following line to your cronfile (type `crontab -e` in a terminal):

```
*  *  *  *  *  python3 /path/to/script/check_gminer.py
```

The script looks every minute if the service runs ant restarts it if not. The question is if it works or not if your GPU has problems. We'll have to see.

**Alternative procedure, if the above method is not sufficient for your situation**

The alternative (reboot) needs administrator privileges. Therefore, if you need to run the reboot command by a cronjob, you need to edit `/etc/crontab` (`sudo nano /etc/crontab`), In which you can set by which user the command should be run (<> `crontab -e`).

Add the line:

```
0 */3 * * * root reboot
```

To the `/etc/crontab` and your computer will restart every three hours.

Comment: Wow, that's nice. I've done what you said. I'll wait to see if this instruction works when the problem occurs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice one and easy re-usable too :-). Though I would suggest /etc/crontab over crontab -e :)

Comment: @Rinzwind You are completely right of course, but I am not sure if gminer runs locally?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Your idea was clever, but as I edited the question, it doesn't solve the problem. Now, can you please guide me how to work with crontab to restart the PC every 3 hours? Actually, restarting has another advantage, the GPUs will rest for about 5 minutes :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Someone else, "Creator", answered the question. Thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: @Majidak I am afraid don't understand much of the pretty crowded comment series beneath your question :), but anyway, it is `* */3 * * * root reboot`, important is that you add it to `/etc/crontab` (`sudo nano /etc/crontab`, not `crontab -e`)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sorry about that. What's the difference between those two crontabs? Admin and non-admin user?

Comment: @Majidak I added the info to my answer :)

Comment: I guess the first star should be changed to ,let's say, 1. Since, the pc will restart at any minute when it is dividable by 3.

Comment: @Majidak Aaarrgh, excuse me, you are right of course, will change it. It should be `0  */3  *  *  *`