# Autoreboot Ubuntu on every 15 days

Tags: cron

I am new on Ubuntu and I want to ask you is the right way to reboot Ubuntu server (14.04.5 LTS) on 2:30 AM of every 15 days (two times of month)?

```
30 2 15/* * * path/to/shutdown --reboot
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13730/how-can-i-schedule-a-nightly-reboot

Comment: Hi thanks....I read this but I want exactly two times of month

Answer (score 0):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604362/quartz-cron-expression-run-every-15-days-ie-twice-in-a-month)

> The following also works fine, it executes your command on the 15th
>   and the 30th at 02:00 AM of every month:
>
> ```
> 0 2 */15 * * <yourCommand>
> ```

Back to your question

> ```
> 0 2 */15 * * shutdown -r now
> ```

Also see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13730/how-can-i-schedule-a-nightly-reboot) to learn more about cron